# Run Rails tests with :memory: database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have a rails app that I use Travis-ci with. To get this to work I hade to change

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

to

```
test:
    <<: *default
    database: ":memory:"
```

However when I run `rake test test/models/patient_test.rb` I get an error but it worked originally. The error says

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError: 

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

However running this doesn't solve the issue

My test is

```
require 'test_helper'

class PatientTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

And my test helper file is

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following line:

```
%x|bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test|
```

somewhere near the top of your test helper. The reason is that in-memory database is being created each time the application starts, fresh and empty. It worked with plain sqlite file, because it was pre-populated with the migrations. Running the command in advance makes not much sense since the in-memory database would be *re-created* on the application start.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I still get the same error.